# Roots of irreducible polynomial over finite field extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $K$ be finite field and $L$ be an extension of $K$ of degree $n$. Fix
>   a monic irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in K[X]$ of degree d dividing n. Show
>   that there is element $\alpha \in L $ which has minimal polynomial
>   $f$ over $K$.

I know that $K$ is isomorphic to field $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ for some $m$. If $m=1$ then $K=\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and we get result from the fact that $L$ is given by roots of polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$, which is product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ of degree $d$ dividing $n$, and hence has to  contain roots of any irreducible polynomial of such degree.

I have trouble with general case when $m\neq1$.

If I take a root $\alpha$ of polynomial $f$ then I get extension $K(\alpha)$ of degree $d$ over $K$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^{md}}$. Field $\mathbb{F}_{p^{md}}$ is given by roots of polynomial $X^{p^{md}}-X$ which is product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ of degree dividing $md$. Hence minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ has to be of degree dividing $md$, and hence also dividing $mn$. Because of that, similarly as in case $m=1$, $L$ has to contain $\alpha$. Is my reasoning correct?

Is there is another, quicker approach?

Comment: As a note on correct syntax (i.e. the rules of formal language), lower-case notation is not very desirable for the indeterminate of a polynomial ring; instead, upper-case letters are (to be) preferred: X, Y, Z etc. Furthermore, given a polynomial $f$ in indeterminate $X$ over ring $A$, the object $f(x)$ would in principle mean the substitution of $x$ in the place of the indeterminate $X$ inside $f$ (in more concise language, this is the image of $f$ through the unique ring morphism  of ''substitution'' taking $X$ to $x$ from $A[X]$ to whatever ring $B$ happens to contain $x$).

Comment: (continuation of the above) hence, $f(X)$ is simply equal to $f$, the underlying substitution morphism being none other than the identity of the polynomial ring $A[X]$. Therefore, it is quite unnecessary to write $f(X)$; in order to specify the notation for the indeterminate, that should be declared from the onset, before even introducing the polynomial itself.

Comment: Thanks, I changed notations. Does my solution look correct?

Comment: It is correct in principle of thought, but a bit sloppy with the details. Without wanting to come off as an arrogant person, I would dare say that the solution below neatly and concisely expresses what you wanted to say.

Comment: Very glad to hear it helps!

Comment: As a note on correct syntax, @ΑΘΩ , I have to disagree most strongly. I see nothing wrong with writing $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$, as long as it’s clear that here, $x$ is an indeterminate. My position is that letters do not have permanent connotations: in number theory, $\pi$ often means something totally other than twice the first real root of $\sin$.

Comment: @Lubin You are entitled to your opinion, and are also right in principle that as long as one makes it clear what one's notation means there shouldn't be any problems of comprehension. However, my main reason for disagreeing with the allotment of lower-case letters for use as polynomial indeterminates is the fact that it is precisely these lower-case letters that I (personally, by virtue of my notation preferences) would want to use to denote generic elements of generic rings that might be involved in the respective setting and which might be substituted in polynomials.

Comment: @Lubin Furthermore, there is the phenomenon of ''psychological impression'' by which one would typically tend to treat the lower-case $x, y, z$ etc as *variables* over which one can quantify (either universally or existentially), case in which a distinguished and distinguishing notation would be preferable to express an object that is -- in the given context -- fixed once and for all, such as a polynomial indeterminate.

Comment: Well, @ΑΘΩ, we have the choice between agreeing to disagree and meeting in the alley behind the bar to settle the thing like gentlemen. (If, of course, you are a masculine person.)

Comment: @Lubin But of course, sir. May I toast a glass of red wine to the spirit of your invitation (and you are indeed not mistaken about me being a man).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most convenient to consider an algebraic closure $F$ of $L$; then $F$ will automatically be an algebraic closure of $K$ containing $L$ as a subextension. The structure of the algebraic extension of a finite field is remarkably simple: for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ there exists a unique subextension $E_n$ of degree $n$ over $K$, given explicitly as the set of all roots of the polynomial (separable over $K$) $X^{q^n}-X$, where $q=|K|$; furthermore, one has

$$F=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} E_n$$

and

$$E_m \subseteq E_n \Leftrightarrow m|n$$

Considering an arbitrary root $x \in F$ of your given polynomial $f$, it is clearly the case that $[K(x):K]=d$ whence $K(x)=E_d \subseteq E_n=L$; therefore, **all the roots of $f$ lie in the subextension $L$**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct proof, for which you need only to know that *a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group $L^*$ of a field is necessarily cyclic* $(*)$. Here your $L$ is an extension of degree $n$ (missing in the first sentence of your post) of a finite field $K=\mathbf F_q$, where $q$ is a power of the characteristic $p$ of $L$. In a fixed algebraic closure $\bar K$, property $(*)$ implies that $L=K(\mu_s)$, where $\mu_s$ denotes the group of ($q^n -1$)-th roots of unity. Now let $f(X)\in K[X]$ be irreducible of degree $d$. Because of $(*)$, the splitting field of $f$ in $\bar K$ is of the form $N=K(\mu_r)$, with $r=q^d -1$. If $d$ divides $n$, then $q^d -1$ divides $q^n -1$, hence $N\subset L$ and we are done.

Comment: How do you know that $q^d-1$ divides $q^n-1$?

Comment: If $d$ divides $n$, write $n=dm$, so that $q^n-1=(q^d)^m-1 $. But $X^m-1=(X-1)(X^{m-1}+...+X+1)$.